# A proof using mathematical induction

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinations

By observing the base cases for $t=2,3$, I conjectured the following general inequality which I don't know is true or false:

$$\frac{(n_{1}+n_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot n_{t})(n_{1}+n_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot n_{t}-1)\cdot \cdot \cdot (n_{1}+n_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot n_{t}-t+1)}{t!}+\frac{(n_{1}+n_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot n_{t-1})(n_{1}+n_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot n_{t-1}-1)\cdot \cdot \cdot (n_{1}+n_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot n_{t-1}-t+2)}{(t-1)!}+\cdot \cdot \cdot+ \frac{(n_{1}+n_{2})(n_{1}+n_{2}-1)}{2!}+n_{1} +2 \leq \frac{(n_{1}+n_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot+n_{t})^{t}}{t^{t-2}} $$

I tried to prove it using mathematical induction and at the last step of mathematical induction, I left with the following inequality to prove:

$$\frac{(n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot+n_{k+1})(n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot+n_{k+1}-1)\cdot \cdot \cdot (n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot+n_{k+1}-k)}{(k+1)!}+\frac{(n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot n_{k})^{k}}{k^{k-2}} \leq \frac{(n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot n_{k+1})^{k+1}}{(k+1)^{(k+1)-2}}$$.

I feel that the second term on the left-hand side will play a big role as its denominator is $k^{k-2}$ which could be helpful to obtain the denominator $(k+1)^{(k+1)-2}$ on the right-hand side of the equation. Further, the following obvious inequality related to first term on the left-hand side could also be useful:

$$\frac{(n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot+n_{k+1})(n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot+n_{k+1}-1)\cdot \cdot \cdot (n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot+n_{k+1}-k)}{(k+1)!} \leq \frac{(n_{1}+n_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot+n_{k+1})^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$.

Any hint or explicit proof will be a great help.